# Excel open very slow if file located in sub-folders

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Sames size of Excel files, it's much slower opened if it is in sub-folders,

For example:

```
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6\file.xlsx.
```

It takes 30 seconds to be opened.

When the same Excel file is moved to:

```
C:\folder1\file.xlsx
```

It takes less than 10 seconds.

Running Excel 2016 in Windows 10. Just completed the Repair by Office. It's very fast if only launch Excel.

Is there a way to make the Excel file located in sub-folders to be opened quicker?

Thank you.

Comment: Make a hardlink to this subfolder near the filesystem's root and use short pathname.

Comment: if the total number of characters in all the folders exceed 254 problems with opening files does happen.

Comment: Alternatively: `subst x: C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6`

Comment: @Akina, could you please share more on the "subst" method?

Comment: Start CMD window. Type `subst /?` and press Enter. Or read somethink like this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst

Comment: @Akina, thank you. would you be interested to post an answer?

Comment: I didn't reproduce the issue with my Excel 2016 and Excel for Office 365 on Windows 10. I find that it's slow when I first double-click to open the workbook. It will be faster when I reopen the workbook. Then I copy and paste the workbook into a sub-folder with a long path. It's very fast to open the workbook.

Comment: @HerbGu, however it's not my case - so I suspect if anything else causes the problem on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share a way worked on my computer. My Excel no long takes abnormally long when opening spreadsheets after following the steps.

[How To Fix ‘Filename Is Too Long’ Issue In Windows](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-fix-filename-is-too-long-issue-in-windows/)

In "Make Windows 10 Accept Long File Paths", with Registry Editor opened, navigate to the location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
```

Double-click on LongPathsEnabled. In the Value data: field, make sure the number 1 is in there. Click OK.

Once the Group Policy Editor opens, navigate to:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem.
```

There the policy Enable Win32 long paths.
Double-click on it to edit the policy setting. Change it from Disabled to Enabled, then click the OK.